# Thermal energy transfer + combined energy question

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential-energy

In thermal energy transfer, why does the total combined energy of all particles remain constant?

Comment: What about the conservation of energy?

Answer (score 0):

Collisions on the molecular level are perfectly elastic according to kinetic theory of gases i.e the energy lost by one particle is gained by the other during collisions. So total energy remains constant.

Answer (score 0):

If by “thermal energy transfer” you mean heat transfer (energy transfer due solely to temperature difference). And if by “combined energy of all the particles” you mean the sum of all the internal kinetic and potential energy of the particles in a substance to or from which the heat is transferred. Then the only way that that energy (internal energy) can remain constant is if the energy value of the heat leaves/enters the substance in some other form in order for there to be conservation of energy.  Generally that would mean that work is either done on or by the substance according to the first law.

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

Where $\Delta U$ is the change in the internal energy of the substance, $Q$ is the heat added to the substance, and $W$ is the work done by the substance.  If $\Delta U=0$ then

$$Q=W$$

Hope this helps.